# eslint - vue/script-indent to ignore object fields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, eslintrc

I have the following ESLint rule setup:

```
"vue/script-indent": [
    "error",
    4,
    {
        "baseIndent": 1,
        "switchCase": 1,
        "ignores":
        [
            "[init.type=\"ObjectExpression\"]",
            "[init.type=\"ArrayExpression\"]"
        ]
    }
]
```

However, I would like the indentation to be ignored for the following case (where an object key's value is another object).

This is the output of the linter:

```
let example =
    {
        example:
            {
                test: 
                    "test"
            }
    }
```

But I want the nested object to be untouched, so it looks like this:

```
let example =
    {
        example:
        {
            test: 
                "test"
        }
    }
```

So it should be an Object that's inside an Object that should be ignored. I would also like to have Arrays inside Objects to be ignored as well (hence why my ignores have Object and Array)

Comment: @GarisMSuero ah yep, forgot to fix.

Comment: @A.Lau Just in case, my edited code does not fix the indention. They both still look the same

Comment: at least those braces are positioned differently :D

Comment: @messerbill If only that was intended! Yay, I fixed it. :)

Comment: @messerbill yeah, I just want the indentation to be different.

Comment: have a look here https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/blob/master/docs/rules/script-indent.md#wrench-options

Comment: @messerbill I'm not sure how to write the AST nodes, I've shown what I've tried but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @A.Lau Do you want the arrays and nested objects to be completely ignored (untouched)? Or formatted in a different way? The question makes it seem like you want both, which doesn't seem possible with `eslint-plugin-vue`. If that's not the case (you only want arrays/nested-objects to be untouched), I have an answer :)

Comment: @tony19 yeah, so nested arrays/objects to be untouched. I will update my question to show

Comment: @tony19 did you have an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following rule configures `vue/script-indent` to ignore nested objects/arrays in `.vue`:

```
"vue/script-indent": [
    "error",
    4,
    {
        "baseIndent": 1,
        "switchCase": 1,
        "ignores": [
            // nested objects, excluding top level of exported object (data, methods, computed, etc.)
            "[value.type='ObjectExpression']:not(:matches(ExportDefaultDeclaration, [left.property.name='exports']) > * > [value.type='ObjectExpression'])",

            // nested arrays
            "[value.type='ArrayExpression']"
        ]
    }
],
```

#### Caveats

- In TypeScript, decorators of class properties (e.g., `@Prop private msg!: string`) cause a linter bug, where every line afterward is ignored by the linter. ([`vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#834`](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/834)) ***Workaround:** Insert an empty method (i.e., `_unused() {}`) as the first element of the class.*
- The order of your object fields could cause the linter to ignore the entire object ([`vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue#833`](https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/833)). ***Workaround:**  Ensure objects have a literal as its first field.*